# How do I emit LLVM IR when building with Bazel?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, bazel

I'm working on a project whose build system is written using Bazel.
Most of the BUILD files in the project creates .so library, and I'm trying to emit LLVM IR of the sources files constituting the shared library, and running some LLVM passes on LLVM IR, then creating the final shared library.
But I have no idea how to modify the build system and emitting LLVM IR. (I'm not familiar with Bazel)

Any helps will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bazel does not support this out of the box. You will need to define your own rules and toolchains. You can follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/toolchains.html) to create a toolchain which transforms source files to LLVM IR. There is a similar tutorial [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html) as well. A solution might look something like this:

1. Rule: transform source files to LLVM IR (many-to-many)
2. Rule: transform LLVM IR to LLVM IR (many-to-many)
3. Rule: transform LLVM IR to shared object (many-to-one)

You will need to write a lot of code for a tool which is, quite frankly, poorly-documented. It might be easier to encode these rules in a regular `makefile` and invoke `make` from the bazel script.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read these tutorials and yes I think you're right, they're poorly documented. I think I'll do what you suggested. Have a great day!